# IoTHubModuleClient Not Receiving Messages

Tags: azure, azure-iot-edge

I am trying to send a JSON data from a module to another module in IoT Edge.

The current routing I have in my deployment is:

```
FROM /messages/* INTO BrokeredEndpoint(\"/modules/target-module/inputs/input1\")
```

The code I have to receive the message from the receiving side is:

```
async def input1_listener(module_client):
        while True:
            try:
                input_message = await module_client.receive_message_on_input("input1")  # blocking call
            except Exception as e:
                traceback.print_exc()
                print("******************* Exception", flush=True)
                print(e)
            if not input_message is None and not input_message.data is None:
                encoding = 'utf-8'
                message_string = input_message.data.decode(encoding)
                # data = json.loads(message_string)
                print(message_string, flush=True)
            else:
                print('I have nothing')
```

And the response I get after I deploy is:

```
Jul 17 08:49:01 : DEBUG:azure.iot.device.common.pipeline.pipeline_thread:Starting on_subscribed in pipeline thread
Jul 17 08:49:01 : DEBUG:azure.iot.device.common.pipeline.pipeline_stages_mqtt:MQTTTransportStage(MQTTSubscribeOperation): SUBACK received. completing op.
Jul 17 08:49:01 : DEBUG:azure.iot.device.common.pipeline.pipeline_ops_base:MQTTSubscribeOperation: completing without error
Jul 17 08:49:01 : DEBUG:azure.iot.device.common.pipeline.pipeline_stages_base:OpTimeoutStage(MQTTSubscribeOperation): Cancelling timer
Jul 17 08:49:01 : DEBUG:azure.iot.device.common.pipeline.pipeline_ops_base:EnableFeatureOperation: Worker op (MQTTSubscribeOperation) has been completed
Jul 17 08:49:01 : DEBUG:azure.iot.device.common.pipeline.pipeline_ops_base:EnableFeatureOperation: completing without error
Jul 17 08:49:01 : DEBUG:azure.iot.device.common.pipeline.pipeline_thread:Starting on_complete in callback thread
Jul 17 08:49:01 : DEBUG:azure.iot.device.common.async_adapter:Callback completed with result None
Jul 17 08:49:01 : INFO:azure.iot.device.iothub.aio.async_clients:Successfully enabled feature:input
Jul 17 08:49:01 : INFO:azure.iot.device.iothub.aio.async_clients:Waiting for input message on: input1...
```

It gets stuck like this. So the last line is telling me the module is not receiving the message. But, I know the code is not wrong because it's a sample code provided by Azure.

They're also on the same docker network:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "azure-iot-edge",
        "Id": "18879945c844d0518c750b8d6abb8bcb656d59402332e957a21da0e774ab1aa6",
        "Created": "2020-07-07T06:19:44.72084088+08:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.18.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.18.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "403bf3baf0868542a71247a4bf5945ac34ca7e10ce78a95b53ca6accee6cd3a8": {
                "Name": "target-module",
                "EndpointID": "41fee1bfeace1c1473ebae9f6cfe039f4f02d2da71ac64a80e2ae192206d2e67",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:05",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.5/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "5f2a43021e84033f195db935634022066a179f9e95a8d32d78026f17c6711746": {
                "Name": "source-module",
                "EndpointID": "ed7518196b8c9d6d1a7079efe2c18cecd73bd04a09b575b27764b205bb0c805b",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:04",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.4/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "71f4a9b2796a9fd45509b7535ec4ea7686ae069f190d1f49e97266ce549925f1": {
                "Name": "edgeAgent",
                "EndpointID": "a771cf3d90e7e7ef4351c03de661ca0e84731b2f196abb37ee592ecf1136db23",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "830de1ac809f15ee0443610d82a092a0dcbde2dcb84cb49cd241ac6e29ef8e7e": {
                "Name": "edgeHub",
                "EndpointID": "31b2c932e1b9e45cc157cb8f17fe9373775dd61567960c1922b684e65eb3c1ed",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

I also did not mess with NetworkConfig in the deployment either.

I know the source module is sending data because when I change the route to:

```
FROM /messages/* INTO $upstream
```

I start receiving telemetry from the source module in Azure IoT Explorer.

I am running this on Raspberry Pi 4 and this is my dockerfile.arm32v7

```
FROM arm32v7/python:3.7-slim-buster

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .
CMD [ "python3", "-u", "./main.py" ]
```

requirements.txt only contains azure-iot-device~=2.1.2

This is the output of iotedge check --verbose

```
Configuration checks
--------------------
√ config.yaml is well-formed - OK
‼ config.yaml has well-formed connection string - Warning
    Device not configured with manual provisioning, in this configuration 'iotedge check' is not able to discover the device's backing IoT Hub.
    To run connectivity checks in this configuration please specify the backing IoT Hub name using --iothub-hostname switch if you have that information.
    If no hostname is provided, all hub connectivity tests will be skipped.
√ container engine is installed and functional - OK
√ config.yaml has correct hostname - OK
√ config.yaml has correct URIs for daemon mgmt endpoint - OK
‼ latest security daemon - Warning
    Installed IoT Edge daemon has version 1.0.9 but 1.0.9.3 is the latest stable version available.
    Please see https://aka.ms/iotedge-update-runtime for update instructions.
‼ host time is close to real time - Warning
    Could not query NTP server
        caused by: could not receive NTP server response: Resource temporarily unavailable (os error 11)
√ container time is close to host time - OK
√ DNS server - OK
√ production readiness: certificates - OK
√ production readiness: container engine - OK
‼ production readiness: logs policy - Warning
    Container engine is not configured to rotate module logs which may cause it run out of disk space.
    Please see https://aka.ms/iotedge-prod-checklist-logs for best practices.
    You can ignore this warning if you are setting log policy per module in the Edge deployment.
‼ production readiness: Edge Agent's storage directory is persisted on the host filesystem - Warning
    The edgeAgent module is not configured to persist its /tmp/edgeAgent directory on the host filesystem.
    Data might be lost if the module is deleted or updated.
    Please see https://aka.ms/iotedge-storage-host for best practices.
‼ production readiness: Edge Hub's storage directory is persisted on the host filesystem - Warning
    The edgeHub module is not configured to persist its /tmp/edgeHub directory on the host filesystem.
    Data might be lost if the module is deleted or updated.
    Please see https://aka.ms/iotedge-storage-host for best practices.

Connectivity checks
-------------------
√ host can connect to and perform TLS handshake with DPS endpoint - OK
‼ host can connect to and perform TLS handshake with IoT Hub AMQP port - Warning
    skipping because of previous failures
‼ host can connect to and perform TLS handshake with IoT Hub HTTPS / WebSockets port - Warning
    skipping because of previous failures
‼ host can connect to and perform TLS handshake with IoT Hub MQTT port - Warning
    skipping because of previous failures
‼ container on the default network can connect to IoT Hub AMQP port - Warning
    skipping because of previous failures
‼ container on the default network can connect to IoT Hub HTTPS / WebSockets port - Warning
    skipping because of previous failures
‼ container on the default network can connect to IoT Hub MQTT port - Warning
    skipping because of previous failures
‼ container on the IoT Edge module network can connect to IoT Hub AMQP port - Warning
    skipping because of previous failures
‼ container on the IoT Edge module network can connect to IoT Hub HTTPS / WebSockets port - Warning
    skipping because of previous failures
‼ container on the IoT Edge module network can connect to IoT Hub MQTT port - Warning
    skipping because of previous failures

9 check(s) succeeded.
6 check(s) raised warnings.
9 check(s) were skipped due to errors from other checks.
```

At this point, I've run out things to look at that I think could cause this problem.

What am I missing?

Answer (score -1):

The issue was your route

Changing it to:

```
FROM /messages/* INTO BrokeredEndpoint("/modules/target-module/inputs/input1")
```

resolved the issue